# bash: Dynamic cross-script variable's value update

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have 2 scripts: **S1.sh** and **S2.sh**.

**S1.sh** can run independently, and can receive positional value from "$1" as an optional parameter. This "$1" value is dynamic, and may be any number between 0 and 9.

```
VAL=$1
```

**S2.sh** is designed for remote triggering of **S1.sh**, and it uses its own "$1" (string value) for a different purposes.

I'm looking for a way to assign "$2" provided to **S2.sh**  to `$VAL` of **S1.sh**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `S2.sh` calls `S1.sh`, use

```
S1.sh "$2"
```

The value of `S2`'s second parameter is passed as the first argument to `S1`.